# Is it possible to use BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE boost variable independently of library's inclusion order?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, header, macros

I am working on a header file, let's call it main_file.h, that includes two other header files, let's call them file_1.h and file_2.h, with the following characteristics:

- file_1.h includes different boost libraries, among which #include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>. The header file list.hpp, includes the definition of the macro BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE, defined as follows:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE)
#   define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE \
        implementation-defined integral constant \
/**/
#endif
```

- inside file_2.h, since I need to change the value of the macro BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE, contains the following two lines:

```
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE 50
```

So basically I am trying to change the default value of the macro BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE, which is 20, to 50.
Now, I have two possible scenarios:

1. if I include first file_2.h and then file_1.h, I don't have any compilation errors
2. if I include first file_1.h and then file_2.h, I get a "redefinition" error, regarding the macro BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE.

In case 1 I suppose that since the macro is already defined in file_2.h, the boost library will not redefine it due to the #if !defined(BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE) mentioned above;
For the second case, I've tried to use in file_2.h an approach like :

```
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
**#undef** BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE 
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE 50
```

But this basically doesn't work. More precisely the undef works well but the value stays set to 20 (default).

Reading the boost documentation I've found the following info:

[boost_doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJacy.png)

It seems that, in order to correctly redefine the macro with a new value, the order of instructions matters, as reported: "In this implementation of the library, BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE has a default value of 20. To override the default limit, define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE to the desired maximum arity rounded up to the nearest multiple of ten **before including any library header**."

This would explain why case 1 is working without any problem.
The problem is that I can't have a software whose correct compilation depends on the order of header file's inclusion.
Is there a solution to this? Thanks

Tried to #undef the macro but it doesn't work

Comment: Define it as a command line argument to the compiler, i.e. `-DBOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE=50`?

Answer (score 0):

Defining preprocessor symbols for libraries is typically handled via **command line options** to the compiler.

How this is done in detail, depends on your infrastructure, in Visual Studio, you would configure it in the project properties:
[image: Preprocessor Configuration in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, are **precompiled headers**.

Either use a **force include**, or add the header manually (the compiler will complain, if you miss it in any source file).

```
// stdafx.h
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE 50

#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
// other includes
```